# No images and fonts production capistrano, rails , ember cli gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember-cli

I am trying to deploy an app which uses `ember-cli-rails` by `capistrano`. Everything works fine but there is no `images` and `fonts` in `production`.
I put my `styles` in `app.scss` and use `url('some.images')` as a helper. I have tried both way to precompile my assets locally then deploy it and not to precompile assets and let the `capistrano` does it. None of the ways worked. There is no `images` and `fonts`. I have tried some other helper like `image-path`, `image_path` , `image-url` , `image_url` so on, but none of them helped. Tried to configure `rails` itself by putting `config.serve.static.assets = true` in `production.rb` even though I do not think it is neccessary, but still no luck. When I inspected the page in `production` it says `can not load the image`. It seems there is something wrong with the helper `(url('some.images'))` I use??
I followed almost all related posted to this problem in `stackoverflow` but none of them worked. I do not know what I am missing here?

app.scss:

```
body {
  background: url('bg.png');
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

production.rb:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

`Capfile` and `deploy.rb` are just normal one which can be used by `capistrano`.
`Rails` vesion is 4.2 and `Ember` version is 0.2.7 .
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that by changing  `config.assets.compile = false` to `true`.it works.